# Yii 2 - CreateForm that pull info&value from a search of another model

Tags: php, yii, yii2

i've a little problem with yii 2. This is my case:
I manage two tables, **Customer** and **Order**, and any Order has a Customer. I've created the relational data and the normal view to create, update, view and delete data from DB. Now i would use the search model of customer in the Order's _form view (to create and update data) to select the customer and pull **customer.id** that i want to save in my **order.id_customer**.

With my solution i can see the gridview with customer search in the create view, but (with RadioColumn) it doesn't return **customer.id** and when i try to filter the data the form doesn't filter anything but it tries to submit my input in to the db.

The old "_form"'s code is on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ni8xX9gs).

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

-----------------------**UPDATE**-----------------------------

After many hours of work i fixed my problem.
Now my gridview is out from activeform, where i copy the radio's returnament through a javascript function.

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var agente = document.getElementById('agente');
var radioSelAgente = document.getElementsByName('radioAgenteId');
function aggiungiAgente(){
    for (var i = 0, length = radioSelAgente.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radioSelAgente[i].checked) {
            document.getElementById('contrattoformativo-id_agente_iscritto').value=radioSelAgente[i].value;
            alert(radioSelAgente[i].value);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
<form id="formAddAgente" onclick="aggiungiAgente()">
    <?php
    $agenteModel = new \backend\models\Agente();
    $agenteSearchModel = new \backend\models\AgenteSearch();
    $agenteDataProvider = $agenteSearchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $agenteDataProvider->pagination->pageSize=5;
    ?>
    <?php 
    echo \kartik\grid\GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $agenteDataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $agenteSearchModel,
        'id'=>'agente',
        'columns' => [
            [
                'class' => '\kartik\grid\RadioColumn',
                'width'=>'36px',
                'name' => 'radioAgenteId',
                'showClear' => false,

                'radioOptions' => function($agenteModel, $key, $index, $column) {
                    return ['value' => $agenteModel->id];
                },

            ],
            'nome',
            'cognome',

        ],
        'export'=>false,
        'pjax'=>true,
        'pjaxSettings'=>[
            'neverTimeout'=>true,
        ],
    ]);
    ?>
</form>
```

And in the active form i have:

```
<?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'id_agente_iscritto') ;?>
```

Bye!

Comment: Hi! Please could you include the contents of the patebin into your question? In a years time, when your pastebin is deleted, your question will be meaningless. See the help section on why Stackoverflow asks you to do this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you tried specifying a filterUrl for the gridview? If you don't then filtering will use the url of the page, and try to submit the form.

Comment: @JoeMiller ok, now the code is also here on stackoverflow ^^

Comment: @JoeMiller i've tried to use filterUrl but nothing is changed; also i don't know why, but the gridview, with radio button, doesn't return the customer's id